# PHP code for filling a select box not working

Tags: php, html

Hey I came up with a small bit of php code, after looking at a few articles, to fill a select box. The code seems relatively inline with a few of the options I saw  yet doesnt actually work in Dreamweaver or in firefox. Heres the code:

```
<select>
    <?php
        for ($day=1; $day <= 31; $day++;) {
            echo '<option value=\"'.$day.'\">'.$day.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Manually inputting the day isnt much of a problem but doing the same for years is not viable at all and I plan on using similar code to do that so this is a pretty big kink in this page. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Captain Obvious here: there aren't always 31 days in a month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `;` after `$day++`

```
<select>
    <?php
        for ($day=1; $day <= 31; $day++) {
            echo '<option value=\"'.$day.'\">'.$day.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in the for loop:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'
```

Remove the extra ';' you have in there...